# Extract image of UISegmentedControl on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol, image-extraction

I am using `UISegmentedControl` (with only one segment) as a button. But problem with this is one cannot change font size in `UISegmentedControl` (possible in iOS-5+ but I am targeting lower versions devices). Is it possible to extract image of `UISegmentedControl` from app so that I can use custom `UIButton` with this image as background?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try UIKit-Artwork-Extractor (look for it on github.com)

Comment: Thanks. it was useful but not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (UIImageView*imgView in segmentControl.subviews) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgView.frame.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [segmentControl.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *yourImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 
}
```

and import QuartzCore.framework

Comment: thanks for the response. This solution works in simulator but fails on device with error message -[UISegment image]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b98c0. (in my case "thisbutton" is UIsegmentedControl with number of segments 1). DO you have any idea what might be the reason?

Comment: but this UIImageView is added by you or is standart ? :)